# OpenFlow: Baseline Flows for Windows environments

Tags: sdn, openflow

I'm currently looking into OpenFlow Networks in a Windows environment. To just get a network to run properly one needs to define quite a few Flows already. Per example, Active Directory communication, DHCP, DNS, WINS and so on.

Now before diving in myself and just examine what hits my Controller and see if I want to open up the communication for that protocol, I was wondering if anyone has done this or something similar already?

Comment: Unfortunately, resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.